# Multiple versions of Qt in a CMake project

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, version

I have a CMake project with various targets which include/link to Qt5. Some targets use a v5.15 build, while others need to use v5.13 from another build directory.

It looks like `find_package` for Qt will cache the package variables and calling it for a second time, even in a sibling directory, will return the cached version of Qt. Trying to use EXACT version failed:

- Because `Qt5Config` doesn't seem to support that.
- Even when I hacked `Qt5Config` and added EXACT version in the `find_package` calls in there, at the end all targets still used one version.

It is hard to believe that CMake requires that there can only be one version of a certain library in a project. So I guess I am missing something. Any ideas?